# $.post - undefined is not an object error

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've written a WordPress plugin and uploaded all it's contents to the usual wp-content/plugins/pluginname folder. There is a js file and a PHP file in it and i try to run the js code, which looks like this:

```
var tvs = {
    landingpage : {
        recommend : { 
            add : function(page_id) {
                $.post('wp-content/plugins/tvs_landingpages/tvs_recommend_add.php', {page_id:page_id}, function(data) {                                             ...do stuff here...(placeholder)
                });
            },//add
        },//recommend
    },//landingpage
}//var tvs
```

After this code is executed i get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.post')
```

What does this mean? Is the path to the php file wrong? How must be the path then when everything is located in wp-content/plugins/tvs_landingspages/...

Comment: Are you sure jQuery loaded.

Comment: Yes. My .js file is included in the head section after jquery...

Comment: is your wordpress site using jQuery in `noConflict` mode?

Comment: charlietfl: Since i use jQuery.post... the error disappeared. Do you know how the correct path has to be in a js file which is located in the plugins folder?

Comment: it is not the path to the js file which causes the problem, but another javascript library using the `$` for some other purpose, overwriting jquerys use of the `$` variable.